# Selenium error 3 when trying to click on DOM?

Tags: php, selenium

so I'm trying out a selenium, ran into a problem, on a page such as

http://store.apple.com/uk/configure/MD235B/A

I'm trying to click the 'add to basket' button, however selenium returns the following responce

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [sessionId] => 1325263169527
        [status] => 13
        [value] => stdClass Object
            (
                [message] => 
                [suppressed] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [localizedMessage] => 
                [cause] => 
                [class] => java.lang.NullPointerException
                [hCode] => 157938893
                [stackTrace] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [fileName] => ClickElement.java
                                [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                                [lineNumber] => 30
                                [className] => org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ClickElement
                                [nativeMethod] => 
                                [methodName] => call
                                [hCode] => -835585793
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [fileName] => ClickElement.java
                                [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                                [lineNumber] => 1
                                [className] => org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ClickElement
                                [nativeMethod] => 
                                [methodName] => call
                                [hCode] => -835585822
                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [fileName] => FutureTask.java
                                [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                                [lineNumber] => 334
                                [className] => java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
                                [nativeMethod] => 
                                [methodName] => innerRun
                                [hCode] => -99875877
                            )

                        [3] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [fileName] => FutureTask.java
                                [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                                [lineNumber] => 166
                                [className] => java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
                                [nativeMethod] => 
                                [methodName] => run
                                [hCode] => -820313654
                            )

                        [4] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [fileName] => ThreadPoolExecutor.java
                                [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                                [lineNumber] => 1110
                                [className] => java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
                                [nativeMethod] => 
                                [methodName] => runWorker
                                [hCode] => -1285150216
                            )

                        [5] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [fileName] => ThreadPoolExecutor.java
                                [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                                [lineNumber] => 603
                                [className] => java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
                                [nativeMethod] => 
                                [methodName] => run
                                [hCode] => -242190659
                            )

                        [6] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [fileName] => Thread.java
                                [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                                [lineNumber] => 722
                                [className] => java.lang.Thread
                                [nativeMethod] => 
                                [methodName] => run
                                [hCode] => -82946343
                            )

                    )

            )

        [class] => org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response
        [hCode] => 189186959
    )
```

I'm trying to call

```
session/'.$sid.'/element/coherent_id_2/click
```

But so far any element I tried to click never works, same with /text, anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error means it can't find the element.

Do you wait until the page is fully loaded before trying to click it? I think the ID is assigned to the DOM element by javascript, so maybe try waiting until the page is fully loaded before clicking it.